# Does touchesBegan work in tvOS?

Tags: tvos

Can someone confirm that touchesBegan and other touches related events do not work in tvOS? Should we use pressedBegan instead? The problem is I want touch detection in the touchpad and pressedBegan is not invoked when someone touches the center of the touchpad.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I receive touches using tvOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32516535/how-can-i-receive-touches-using-tvos)

Answer (score 2):

Presses refer to button presses and not to the touchpad.

Touches do exist (for the touchpad) but they're 'indirect' and have no actual location - well they have a location but that's assumed to be in the centre of the current view and any movement you make is judged relative to that.

More information [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/DetectingButtonPressesandGestures.html).